# Display the orders in which more than one article is ordered

Tags: mysql

I tried to display the entries in table where the order has more than one article: but it´s not working the way I tried it. Can somebody show me what´s wrong?!

Here´s what I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableX
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(Ordernumber) FROM TableX AS a WHERE a>1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a subquery to identify the order numbers having more than one article, then join this subquery to your original table to obtain the full records for these matching orders.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TableX t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Ordernumber
    FROM TableX
    GROUP BY Ordernumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.Ordernumber = t2.Ordernumber
```

This query assumes that all articles within a given order are unique.  If duplicate articles could occur, and you would not count duplicates, then you can use the following `HAVING` clause instead:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT article) > 1
```

Another option:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableX
WHERE Ordernumber IN
(
    SELECT Ordernumber
    FROM TableX
    GROUP BY Ordernumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Works, but it´s pretty slow: is there any faster possibility?

Comment: I don't see any way around doing the aggregation via a `GROUP BY` query.  Let me give you another option.